# csquotes chars?

Tags: csquotes

Does anyone have recommendations for quote chars for the csquotes package? What's standard practice? I was thinking maybe the following, but note the comment.

```latex
\MakeOuterQuote{"} 
\MakeInnerQuote{'} % this is invalid, as is ' for the outer quote, for some reason 
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»} 
\MakeBlockQuote{<}{|}{>}
```

Comment: Which language is your document in? Do you want to override the default (language-based) quote characters?

Comment: British English. Do you mean the parsed or the displayed quote characters?

Comment: By 'default' quote characters, I mean the ones used in `\enquote`.

Comment: Oh, the auto-quoting command... should I be using that by default? It displays the right quote characters, I just mean when it comes to parsing quote characters in regular text in the LaTeX code.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other. To me, one of the main points of the `csquotes` package is to give its users an opportunity to use a high-level or "meaning-ful" command, such as `\enquote`, instead of having to busy oneself with low-level implementation details. What should be the default for the actual quoting characters is heavily determined by the typographic conventions of the language the document is written in. Some languages have for more than one group of quote characters; the `csquotes package makes it easy to select from the available options.

Comment: Sure, but another big point of csquotes is to allow you to type `"foo"` rather than having to type ``\`foo'`` to get proper quotes. This doesn't work unless one does `\MakeOuterQuote{"}`.

Comment: I use either the third version or \enquote. I would avoid using ascii chars, this can easily clash with other uses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What do you mean "version"?